# Summing Mongoid BigDecimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Mongoid 3 documentation shows you can do simple sums using something like this: `Band.sum(:likes)`

I have the following simple models:

```
class Project
  ...
  has_many :subprojects
  ...
end

class Subproject
  ...
  field :subtotal, :type => BigDecimal, :default => 0
  ...
end
```

How do I sum `subtotal` across each `Project`?

For example, I tried

`Project.first.subprojects.sum(:subtotal)` it returns 0.

But
`Project.first.subprojects.first.subtotal` returns `#<BigDecimal:7fcb0d77b958,'0.11054E3',18(18)>`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I tested how Mongoid stores `BigDecimal`:

`rails c`:

```
class Test
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :decimal, type: BigDecimal
end
test = Test.new
test.decimal = BigDecimal.new(123, 456)
test.save
```

I then queryed the database:

```
> db.tests.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52e0ed4bb2e8c9ea34000001"), "decimal" : "123.0" }
```

You clearly see that the `BigDecimal` is stored as a string, thus explaning why you can't `sum` it.

---

Howevery, you can try to parse it then sum it using a map/reduce :

```
map = %Q{
  function() {
    emit("BigDecimalSum", { decimal: parseFloat(this.decimal) });
  }
}

reduce = %Q{
  function(key, values) {
    var result = { sum: 0 };
    values.forEach(function(value) {
      result.sum += value.decimal;
    });
    return result;
  }
}

Test.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true)
```

I've just tester the `parseFloat` in mongo client and it works, so this map/reduce should work too.

Answer (score -1):

To sum `BigDecimal` fields in Mongoid you use the block form of `#sum`:

`sum = 0
Project.first.subprojects.sum do |subproject|
  sum += subproject.subtotal
end`

Comment: This has nothing to do with Mongoid, you could use any ORM/ODM behind project it should behave the same. At least try to fetch only the field you need.

Comment: Geoffroy, I interpret your comment as unnecessarily abrasive. The question was very clearly related to Mongoid, as Mongoid has a built-in `sum` method. Dean was asking how something similarly could be used for `BigDecimal`. It's true that my solution does not depend on Mongoid, but it is still a valid answer to the question. Also, this is not the forum to lecture me about fetching only the fields I need; I gave a straight answer to a straight question.

Comment: Joost, my comment was not meant to be abrasive, just an advice on how to improve your answer and make it more mongoid-specific ;)